# Table not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table from a searched data scroll but it is not working. I don't know if it is something wrong with my css. I want it to scroll vertically. :(

This is the css code I use to do the table scroll

```
    <style type="text/css">
table{
background-color:#EBEBEB;
}
th{
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <style type="text/css">
    table {
      table-layout:fixed;
         width:100%;
         border:0px solid ; /*border merah d luar*/

             word-wrap:break-word;
            overflow:scroll;
            }
            p   {font-size:9px}

         tbody { height:20em;  overflow:scroll; width:auto}
     td { height:auto; }

    </style>
```

This is the code for the table that I wanted to scroll.

```
    <table width='100%' background="pictures/bg.jpg" id='header' color='black'>

      <thead>
        <tr>
        <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">       </span></div></td> 
         <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Kod Sekolah</span></div></td>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Nama Sekolah</span></div></td>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">PTJ</span></div></td>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Server</span></div></td>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">PC</span></div></td>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">NB</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Mono Laser</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Color Laser</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Dot Matrix</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">LCD</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Set LAN</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Jumlah Kos</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Dibayar</span></div></td> 
          <td width="50%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2 style1">Tanggungan</span></div></td> 
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
<?php 
    if(($_REQUEST['action']=="search")or
    ($_REQUEST['criteria']!="")){?>


      <?php 
      do { 
      if($_REQUEST[category]=="negeri"){ $searching=$row_school['negeri'];
      }else if($_REQUEST[category]=="daerah"){ $searching=$row_school['daerah'];
      }else if($_REQUEST[category]=="kod_sekolah"){ $searching=$row_school['kod_sekolah'];}

      if($searching==$_REQUEST[criteria]){

      ?>


      <table width='100%' border="1" id='header' color='black'>
       <thead>
      <tr>

        <td align="left" valign="top" width="7%"><form action="" method="post" name="xsearch" id="xsearch">
          <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="edit">
            <input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="EDIT">
          <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_school['id']; ?>">
          <input name="category" type="hidden" id="category" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['category'];?>">
        </form>
        </td>


        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['kod_sekolah']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['nama_sekolah']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['ptj']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['server']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['pc']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['nb']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['mono_laser']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['color_laser']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['dot_matrix']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['lcd']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['set_lan']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['jumlah_kos']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['dibayar']; ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_school['tanggungan']; ?></td>



      </tr>

      </table>
      </thead>
```

I hope someone can point out what should be corrected.:(

Comment: It might be easier for others to help you if you create a jsFiddle demo / sample.

Comment: I put it in a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/8UKJa/

Comment: Scroll where? horizontally? vertically? are you looking for a table cell to scroll? or the documdent to scroll?

Comment: I need to scroll vertically. I need the table cell to scroll vertically. :(

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: scroll` isn't supported on all browsers for Table and Table Body tags.  I believe Firefox gets it right, but I know IE doesn't tend to.  It's completely dependent on version.  There are a number of css / js solutions to the problem (search CSS Play for one that works most of the time).  It's not a matter of simply using the css attribute though.  Most of them require additional container divs, and often multiple tables.

Comment: I did the overflow:scroll and it add a scroll bar vertically and horizontally on each row. I don't know if its something wrong with my code or the position of tags in the codes.:(

Comment: @Nielsen - The problem is that the property is not widely supported for the element type that you're attempting to assign it to.  Please refer to this page: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html.  It contains two methods that should help you achieve what you're after.  They require multiple additional containers, not just a single table element.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to build a 2 different tables. one for the head fields, and one for the data.

there's the example :

```
< table width="500" border="0"><br>
  < tr><br>
    < td width="33%">Head One</td><br>
    < td width="33%">Head Two</td><br>
    < td width="33%">Head Three</td><br>
  < /tr><br>
  < tr><br>
    < td colspan="3" style="max-height:200px; overflow:auto; <?php //Here it is. ?>"><br>
    < table width="100%" border="0" id="data"><br>
      < tr><br>
        < td width="33%">Data One</td><br>
        < td width="33%">Data Two</td><br>
        < td width="33%">Data Three</td><br>
      < /tr><br>
    < /table></td><br>
  < /tr><br>
</table><br>
```

Comment: please finish the table code, it's just miss the end comand tag. and i  give a space in every first tag.